# Xamarin Forms envío de múltiples imágenes a servidor

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarinforms

Estoy con el desarrollo de una app y tengo que subir a un servidor imágenes, pero tiene que ser una subida en segundo plano.

Con iOS no he tenido problemas usando:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask(() =>{});
```

He conseguido enviar hasta 300 imágenes (son imágenes de tasaciones por lo que estoy hablando de al menos 100 imágenes), pero en Android siempre me da problemas.

Tengo un `ForegroundService` para que se vaya ejecutando el proceso de subida pero, como digo, en Android o me devuelve error con los sockets o se queda congelada y no sigue el proceso.

He probado enviando las imágenes secuencialmente (craso error), las he enviado de 5 en 5 con un método recursivo viendo cuáles fallan y enviándolas de nuevo (hasta 3 intentos), he probado con tasks pero tampoco:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

//...

Task t = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

He probado con `Parallel`, pero de nuevo el problema de sockets y ahora estoy probando a enviarlas con `MultipartFormDataContent` agrupándolas de 5 en 5:

```
content.Add(new StreamContent(item.imageStream), "...", "...");
```

y, como siempre, iOS me hace el envío sin problemas pero en Android no hay manera.

¿Sabéis de qué forma puedo hacerlo para poder enviarlas? ¿Hay alguna limitación por defecto en Android que no permita hacer una subida de tantas imágenes?

El envío de las imágenes lo hago en base64 menos en el último intento `MultipartFormDataContent` que le paso el stream de la imagen.